# how to stop handler when application goes from foreground to background

Tags: android

i called handler method in onresume method and it is repeated task which repeats for every 20 seconds ,then when application goes to background i am calling handler method removecallbacks(null) to stop it.But it is not working...

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    handler.removeCallbacks(null);
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {     
    super.onResume();
    //new AsynchHttpDownload(true,this, "GetReviewsNew",  2, ReviewsActivity.this).execute();

    customHandler = new android.os.Handler();

   //   customHandler.notify();  

    isRunAlways=true;
    runAnimation=true;
    if((runThread==null)||(runThread!=null&&!runThread.isAlive())){
        runThread=new Thread(thread);
        runThread.start();
    }

    pre_empList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    TimTask();
}


public void TimTask()
  {

    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread,20000);
   // 
   }

    public Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable()
    {

          public void run()
          { 
              Log.d("Repeat Tag","Repeat after 20 sec");
            //  spin.setVisibility((View.VISIBLE));
              new GetSizeFromUpdateReviews().execute();
              customHandler.postDelayed(this, 20000);

          }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
```

instead of

```
handler.removeCallbacks(null);
```

Comment: sir i used  'handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);' but it not worked  actually i am using asyn task in timmethod which executes for every 30 seconds but when application goes backgroung it has to stop because i called handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread),and i am seeing the progress bar for first then it appears for 3 seconds and then it appears for 20 seconds then again after 3 seconds why it is occuring if u want i can post remaining code

Comment: sir i used 'handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);' but it not worked actually i am using asyn task in timmethod which executes for every 30 seconds but when application goes backgroung it has to stop because i called handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread),and when i comes to foregroungd i am seeing the progress bar ,it appears first and after for 3 seconds and then it appears after  20 seconds then again after 3 seconds why it is occuring if u want i can post remaining code i just progress bar to appear once ..i.e to show user it loads for every 30 seconds ...